# Fresh laravel lumen cannot find controller reside under subfolder of controllers

Tags: laravel, lumen

Fresh laravel `lumen 5.8` installed but controller name cannot be found in route

I created `UserController` in `App\Http\Controllers\User`

User Controller Content:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      return 'User list';
   }
}
```

Loaded in route:

```php
$router->get('/user', 'User\UserController@index')
```

Error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController does not exist

I also tried with absolute namespace `App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@index` but it still doesn't work.

It works if I don't put `UserController` in User folder

Comment: Try changing namespace of the controller to `namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;`

Comment: I will convert it to an answer, you may mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `UserController`'s namespace to:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing namespace of the controller to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   // ...
}
```